# Why is it not recommended praxis to call a class method by passing an instance variable?

Tags: python

I'm reading through [this guide](http://simeonvisser.com/posts/python-3-using-yield-from-in-generators-part-2.html) on using the `yield from` keyword, where she inserts the following parenthesis:

> Note that it is not recommended practice to call a class method
>   (self.child_iterate) by passing an instance variable (i.e., the
>   self.left and self.right arguments) but that is a topic for a
>   different post.

For me, the reason why this is not recommended is not very clear, and would love to hear an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

It's not 100% clear from context, but I think the suggestion being made here is that if you need to pass around instance state to a class method, it might as well be an instance method (perhaps one that just calls out to the class method if you want that code to be externally reusable). This reduces the complexity of calls to this method because you don't have to pass around instance data explicitly.

Comment: Calling a class method using `self.foo()` doesn't pass any instance state to the method.  It will pass the type of `self` as first argument to `foo()`, not `self` itself.

Comment: @SvenMarnach No, but calling `self.foo(self.left, self.right)` passes instance state to `foo` - namely the values of `self.left` and `self.right`.

Comment: @sepp2k: Thanks for the clarification, I misread the question.